# Perl Windows command fails

Tags: windows, perl, psexec

I'm trying to run a simple query on network computers to get their Windows' version. This command runs, and returns expected results, when used from the command line:

```
psexec \\comp_name reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId
```

but when run from Perl using:

```
system("psexec \\\\$comp_name reg query 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' /v ReleaseId")
```

I get the error from REG `ERROR: Invalid key name.` Considering that both commands are the same, I cannot figure out why I am getting an error when running it from Perl. My only assumption is the way it's resolving the quotes. Note that this problem persists regardless of whether I use system, exec, or  ``` `` ```. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a string interpolation issue?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!! It would have identified your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double up all of the backslashes:

```
system("psexec \\\\$comp_name reg query 'HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion' /v ReleaseId")
```

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the problem. This, and apparently it had to be `\"HKLM...\"`